# Recognize browser close in wicket

Tags: wicket

Is there a reliable way to detect the closing of the browser tab or window on the server side in a wicket application?
It must work under firefox version 68.11.0 or higher. I use wicket 8.8.0.

I tried it with websockets and catching the connection close event. But unfortunately this event is also raised when a page is refreshed (F5).

```
new WebSocketBehavior() {
    @Override
    protected void onClose(ClosedMessage message) { // invoked on tab close, window close and unfortunately on page reload
        super.onClose(message);
        log.info("Connection for page = '{}' closed.", message.getKey());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From browser point of view there is no difference between `closing the tab` and `refreshing the tab`. In both cases the browser fires `beforeunload` JavaScript event and closes all open connections (WebSocket, ServerSideEvent, Ajax).

So, you can use

```
page.add(new AjaxEventBehavior("beforeunload") {
   @Override public void onEvent(AjaxRequestTarget target) {...}
});
```

but this just tell you that the user navigates away from the current page. There is no info what comes next.